# Flutter SOAP api request

Tags: php, flutter, dart, soap, phpmyadmin

I am trying to build a SOAP API request from my flutter code. The goal is to request with a name and then the API will return a response saying "Hello, (with the name) "This is my code:

This is the url:

```
final url = 'http://localhost/MyServiceServer.php';
```

This is the function:

```
    Future<String> sayHello() async {
    const name = 'John';
    final response = await http.post(
      Uri.parse(url),
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'text/xml;charset=UTF-8',
        'SOAPAction': 'http://localhost/MyServiceServer.php#sayHello'
      },
      body: '''
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://localhost/MyServiceServer.php" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <ns1:sayHello>
        <name xsi:type="xsd:string">$name</name>
      </ns1:sayHello>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
  </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
''',
    );

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      final xml = response.body;
      final regex = RegExp(r'<return.*?>(.*?)<\/return>');
      final match = regex.firstMatch(xml);
      final message = match?.group(1) ?? '';
      return message;
    } else {
      print('Failed to call SOAP API: ${response.statusCode}');
      print('Response body: ${response.body}');
      throw Exception('Failed to call SOAP API');
    }
  }
```

This is my PHP file that is responsible for the SOAP API response:

```
    <?php
class MyService {
   public function sayHello() {
      $xml = file_get_contents('php://input');
      $dom = new DOMDocument();
      $dom->loadXML($xml);
      $name = $dom->getElementsByTagName('name')->item(0)->nodeValue;
      $message = "Hello, $name!";
      echo $message;
      echo "<br>";
      echo "Name: " . $name;
      return $message;
   }
}

$server = new SoapServer(null, array('uri' => 'http://localhost/MyServiceServer.php'));
$server->setClass('MyService');
$server->handle();
?>
```

But it is throwing me an error:

```
flutter: Failed to call SOAP API: 500
flutter: Response body: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><SOAP-ENV:Body><SOAP-ENV:Fault><faultcode>SOAP-ENV:Client</faultcode><faultstring>Bad Request</faultstring></SOAP-ENV:Fault></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>

[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: Exception: Failed to call SOAP API
#0      _MyHomePageState.sayHello (package:flutter_todoapp/main.dart:78:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
```

I can't find what is causing the error please help.

Comment: if the status code is 500, then it must be issue in server code.

Comment: When I call the SOAP api using CURL, it is working properly, returning me the expected response.